# How do I block a device from accessint internet through ASUS RT-AC68U router

Tags: router, internet, blocking

I have some internet connected appliances connected to the wireless network. I want them to be able to give cycle end notices to anyone in the house (on the wireless net) but not 100 miles away (e.g., my son gets every notice of our laundry getting done).
   I tried the firewall network services filter. I just filled in the machine IP addresses. Assumed the blank fields would block all traffic. TCP protocol was selected (had to pick something). This did not work. Any idea what would?

Comment: "_but not 100 miles away (e.g., my son gets every notice of our laundry getting done)_" ... is your son living at home? If not, then why does he have the app / login for your appliances? What are the appliances?

Answer (score 15):

On the network map screen (main screen) click "Clients", then click on the icon next to device details.

On the new popup screen you can switch "block internet access" ON/OFF

Comment: Not sure if happened to you but I needed to reboot my router (RT-AX92U)

Comment: Can confirm changes were instantaneous for me (RT-AC68U).

Answer (score 1):

You can use parental controls to block it from accessing the internet

Comment: The parental controls seem to only block certain content (e.g., social media, on-line games, etc.), not entire access to the outside network.